# Can't locate DBI.pm

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to launch this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Oracle:host=lonlin2;sid=TIMFX1AD;port=1524','xbsesdbo','xbsesdbo123' )  || die ( $DBI::errstr . "\n" );

my $query= "SELECT * FROM product_elements WHERE element_id = 1001";
my $queryHandler= $dbh->prepare($query);

my $result= $queryHandler->execute();


open(fileHandler,"> note.txt");

print fileHandler "Risultato query: $result\n";

my $e= $dbh->disconnect();
close(fileHandler);
```

When I launch this script I receive this error:

> Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/perl_32/lib/5.8.3/IA64.ARCHREV_0-thread-multi /opt/perl_32/lib/5.8.3 /opt/perl_32/lib/site_perl/5.8.3/IA64.ARCHREV_0-thread-multi /opt/perl_32/lib/site_perl/5.8.3 /opt/perl_32/lib/site_perl /opt/perl_32/lib/vendor_perl/5.8.3/IA64.ARCHREV_0-thread-multi /opt/perl_32/lib/vendor_perl/5.8.3 /opt/perl_32/lib/vendor_perl .) at ./prova.pl line 3.

I've got all installed! DBI.pm is installed!

Comment: If you installed it, you either installed it using/for a different `perl`, or you instructed Perl to install it to a non-standard directory and you haven't told `perl` to look into that directory. 1) How did you install it? 2) What's the full path to `DBI.pm`?

Comment: Try the command `perldoc -l DBI`. If DBI.pm is installed and is in Perl's Include path, you'll see the location of the installation. There could be multiple Perls installed on your system and you might be accessing the wrong one. What's your shebang line like? I use `#! /usr/bin/env perl` to pick up the Perl version my Path uses, and I use [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) to handle multiple Perl versions.

Comment: And in which of those directories listed in the error message above is it installed?

Answer (score 58):

If you have root, type in console (Debian/Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libdbi-perl
```

Answer (score 12):

If you don't have active perl (and hence don't have ppm), you can also get DBI like this:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBI'
```

You may need to install drivers for Postgres like this:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBD::Pg'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! However, I had to run it with "sudo", since I don't have enough privileges. I have installed it with "sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install DBI'.

Answer (score 11):

For redhat/centos users:

```
sudo yum -y install perl-DBI
```

Answer (score 3):

DBI isn't in your `@INC` path, which tells perl where to look for custom modules. This is probably because you've installed them using the `cpan` tool as a non-root user, which won't have write access to the default include paths.

You will need to locate `DBI.pm` and other packages, and move them into your `@INC` path.

Alternatively, find the packages you've installed and add the install path into your library path, for one time use:

```
PERL5LIB=/path/to/modules perl yourscript.pl
```

And for a more permanent solution, add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PERL5LIB=/path/to/modules
```

Comment: How i can find the path of DBI package?

Comment: @chaw359 `find / -name 'DBI.pm' 2>/dev/null` would do it on UNIX-like OS.

Comment: @chaw359 — How did you install it?

Comment: Where i ve to use "PERL5LIB=/path/to/modules perl yourscript.pl" ?? In the code or is a command for unix? Please make me an example :D

Comment: @chaw359 That would be on the command line, when you run your script.

Answer (score 0):

For alpine users use [perl-dbi](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=perl-dbi): `apk add perl-dbi`

Answer (score 0):

For arch linux users:

```
sudo pacman -S perl-dbi
```