# Cannot find DBI.pm even if it's in the path

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, munin

I'm trying to install the [munin-mysql plugin](https://github.com/kjellm/munin-mysql/archive/master.zip) but I'm facing a strange error. Munin complains that it cannot find `DBI.pm` in the @INC:

```
[root@mybox perl5]# munin-run mysql
Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /etc/munin/plugins/mysql line 127.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /etc/munin/plugins/mysql line 127.
```

However, it *is* indeed in the path, and precisely at `/usr/local/lib64/perl5`. It was installed via the command `cpanm DBI`.
In fact, there are several `DBI.pm` files; how do I know which one is to be used?

```
[root@mybox perl5]# find / -name DBI.pm
/root/.cpan/build/DBI-1.634-Aazmvi/blib/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
/root/.cpan/build/DBI-1.634-Aazmvi/blib/lib/DBI.pm
/root/.cpan/build/DBI-1.634-Aazmvi/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
/root/.cpan/build/DBI-1.634-Aazmvi/DBI.pm
/root/.cpanm/work/1460983027.32244/DBI-1.634/blib/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
/root/.cpanm/work/1460983027.32244/DBI-1.634/blib/lib/DBI.pm
/root/.cpanm/work/1460983027.32244/DBI-1.634/lib/Bundle/DBI.pm
/root/.cpanm/work/1460983027.32244/DBI-1.634/DBI.pm
/root/munin-mysql-master/t/mock/DBI.pm
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/Bundle/DBI.pm
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/DBI.pm
```

Related questions:

- [Can't locate DBI.pm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568836/cant-locate-dbi-pm)
- [Unable to locate DBI.pm module in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405894/unable-to-locate-dbi-pm-module-in-perl)

Comment: Check permission on DBI.pm file.

Comment: Already done, permissions on file and parent dirs are 755.

Comment: What's the result of the command `perl -MDBI -e1`?

Comment: The command outputs nothing and exits with zero status.

Comment: The correct instance to use is `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/DBI.pm`. The others are mostly work files from cpan, cpanm and munin. The other one in `/usr/local/lib64/perl5` is actually module `Bundle::DBI`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`munin-run` switches users](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/munin-run). The default user is `nobody`. That user probably does not have permission to read the file.

> The script must be run with sufficient privileges, usually as root, as it switches to either munin-node's default user (often "nobody") or any user specifically configured to run the given plugin.

Check with `munin-run --debug` what user it's running as and check that user can read `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/DBI.pm`.